Error imposible de handlear en Express
estoy creando una API con Express, pero al pasarle un JSON con un formato incorrecto lanza un error que cierra el servidor, en vez de handlearlo:
POST http://localhost:3000/
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "SR73",
    "password": "1234",
}

El codigo de la api es el siguiente:
import express from 'express'

const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? 3000

app.disable('x-powered-by')

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
})

...
Endpoints varios
...

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})


Si a la API si le envió un JSON correcto funciona correctamente, pero me gustaría evitar que se cerrase el servidor, por ejemplo enviando un status 400.
También he intentado a poner todo el código de la app en un try catch, tal que así:
try {
  const app = express()

  const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? 3000

  app.disable('x-powered-by')

  app.use(express.json())

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
  })

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
  })
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}

Pero la API se sigue cerrando.
¿Cuál es la forma correcta de handlear el error?, por cierto, el error es el siguiente:
SyntaxError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 53
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\Users\sr73\Desktop\Programm\javascript\projects\bookLibrary\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:92:19)
    at C:\Users\sr73\Desktop\Programm\javascript\projects\bookLibrary\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\sr73\Desktop\Programm\javascript\projects\bookLibrary\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:238:16)
    at done (C:\Users\sr73\Desktop\Programm\javascript\projects\bookLibrary\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:227:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\sr73\Desktop\Programm\javascript\projects\bookLibrary\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:287:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)


Prueba con alguna de las soluciones que sugieren aquí

¿¿¿¿imposible de qué??? :D :D :D
